# CommonChunkPlugin is not a constructor

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

Getting this error for some strange reason

TypeError: webpack.CommonsChunkPlugin is not a constructor

Other plugins are working fine for me:

```
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    // create global variables accessible on server and client
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because it's not `webpack.CommonsChunkPlugin` but `webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin`

References:

- https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#commonschunkplugin